# Highlight row if partial text matches in either of two columns

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet that has a list of job names, and then the last failure and success of each job. The dates are listed with duration words instead of dates, ie `1 mo 12 days` or `3 days 6 hr`.

I want to highlight a row if either the last success OR the last failure was over a year ago. This means highlighting the row if column `B` or column `C` contains the text `yr`.

Example data:

```
job A | 1 yr 2 days | 1 day
job B | 2 mo 1 day  | 1 yr 3 days
job C | 1 day       | 1 mo 2 day
```

In this case I'd want to highlight rows 1 and 2 as both contain a date over a year old.

I tried the following formulas:

```
=OR($B2="yr", $C2="yr")
# doesn't recognize "yr" - presumably this is an absolute match

=OR($B2=".*yr.*", $C2=".*yr.*")
# attempted to add wildcards but it's not matching anything
```

The formula works great if I do an absolute match, ie `1 day` will highlight rows 1 and 3, but doesn't work with pattern matches. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `REGEXMATCH` :

```
=OR(REGEXMATCH($B2,"yr"),REGEXMATCH($C2,"yr"))
```

Second entry is a JS regular expression. You can build it with a tool like [regexr.](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Ahhh, I somehow never saw regexmatch - that did it! Thanks!